# .NET 4.8 Conexion SQL Server utilizando archivo para que se guarde dicha conexion

Tags: c#, sql-server, net

Hola queridos programadores, soy algo principiante en el mundo de la programacion y las bases de datos, queria saber si hay alguna forma de que se pueda realizar alguna conexion con el servidor de mi SSMS (laptop) utilizando algun texto que sea ingresado a traves de mi formulario y que se quede guardado cuando cierre la aplicacion, algo asi como una configuracion. Tengo que realizar una app que tenga una conexion con mi BD de manera local y quiero que cuando alguien se instale el programa ellos puedan realizar la conexion con su equipo donde se encuentre la bd.

Este es mi Cs donde tengo mi conexion para poder acceder a traves de cualquier form

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Sistema
{
    class ConexionSQL
    {
        public SqlConnection con;
        public void conexion()
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"server=LAPTOP----;database=---;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;");
        }

    }
```

Y esto es un ejemplo de un formulario donde hago uso de la libreria sqlclient y hago una consulta

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Sistema
{
    public partial class PantallaInicio : Form
    {
        ConexionSQL cone = new ConexionSQL();

        public PantallaInicio()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void PantallaInicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblFechaActual.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
            cone.conexion();
            string query = ("SELECT * FROM Unidades");
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, cone.con);
            cone.con.Open();
            SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
            while (registro.Read())
            {
                ComboBUnidad.Items.Add(registro["ID_Unidad"].ToString());
            }
            cone.con.Close();
        }

        private void TxtUsuario_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(TxtUsuario.Text == "Usuario")
            {
                TxtUsuario.Text = "";
                TxtUsuario.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void TxtContraseña_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TxtContraseña.Text == "Contraseña")
            {
                TxtContraseña.Text = "";
                TxtContraseña.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                TxtContraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = true;
            }
        }

        private void TxtUsuario_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TxtUsuario.Text == "")
            {
                TxtUsuario.Text = "Usuario";
                TxtUsuario.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            }
        }

        private void TxtContraseña_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TxtContraseña.Text == "")
            {
                TxtContraseña.Text = "Contraseña";
                TxtContraseña.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                TxtContraseña.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            }
        }

        private void BtnCerrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void BtnMaximizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(Handle).WorkingArea;
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            else
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void BtnMinimizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        //Drag Form
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "ReleaseCapture")]
        private extern static void ReleaseCapture();
        [DllImport("user32.DLL", EntryPoint = "SendMessage")]
        private extern static void SendMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

        private void BarraTitulo_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ReleaseCapture();
            SendMessage(this.Handle, 0x112, 0xf012, 0);
        }

        private void BtnInicioSesion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            if (TxtUsuario.Text != "" && TxtContraseña.Text != "" && ComboBUnidad.Text != "") {
            cone.conexion();
            cone.con.Open();
            string query = ("SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE ID_Usuario=@idus AND ID_Unidad=@iduni AND Contraseña=@contra");
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, cone.con);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idus", TxtUsuario.Text);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iduni", ComboBUnidad.Text);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contra", TxtContraseña.Text);
            SqlDataReader lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (lector.Read())
            {
                cone.con.Close();
                this.Hide();
                PantallaMenu pantalla_atu = new PantallaMenu();
                pantalla_atu.nomb = TxtUsuario.Text;
                pantalla_atu.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datos incorrectos, por favor intente de nuevo");
                cone.con.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ingresa los datos requeridos para el inicio de sesion");
            }
        }

        private void TxtUsuario_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```